# How to run a closing script when issuing docker-compose stop or crtl-c

Tags: docker-compose, init, bash-trap

I'm doing:

```sh
docker-compose up
```

my service is essentially to run `netlify dev`

Because we may deal with several `_redirects_xxx` files, I have in my `entrypoint.sh` something like:

```sh
cleanup() {
    if $remove; then
        echo ">>> Removing created _redirects"
        rm -fv /app/_redirects
    else
        echo "Bye!"
    fi
}
reddoc=${1}
remove=false
if [ ! -s "/app/_redirects" ]; then
    echo ">>> Copying ${reddoc} to _redirects"
    cp /app/${reddoc} /app/_redirects
    remove=true
else
    echo ">>> _redirects already exists"
fi
trap 'cleanup' INT TERM EXIT
echo ">>> remove = ${remove}"
netlify dev
```

From my `docker-compose.yml`, I have:

```yaml
...
   frontend:
      volumes:
      - ./frontend/:/app
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
...
      init: true
      command: bash ./entrypoint.sh _redirects_docker
...
```

The point is, some developers have their own `_redirects` file so when starting the docker service, we don't want to override their setup. But for all other developers (mostly backend guys) we want the `_redirects_docker` to take place but, when stopping the frontend service (e.g. `crtl`-C or `docker-compose stop / down`), I'd like a closure step to remove the `_redirects` file if it was not there from the very beginning.

I've tried, as you may see, above with `TRAP` and `init` but it's not working to delete `_redirects`.

**UPDATE 25/Nov/2020**

Not a solution yet, but I found out that if I do this in another terminal:

```sh
docker kill -s hup frontend_1
```

It triggers the trap and does what I want. However using `-s int` or `-s term` does not do anything.

**UPDATE 26/Nov/2020**

I found out that the issue is on how to `trap` `netlify dev`. If I use a zombie line instead, like, `while true; do :; done`, stopping the docker service, no matter how, except with a pure `kill`, will trigger the routine `cleanup`.

Honestly, an `exitpoint:` pragma in `docker-compose.yml` would be all I ever wanted.

Comment: Anything in the container filesystem will automatically get removed when the container exits; you don't need a special cleanup hook.  If you're overwriting the application code in the image with a bind mount, consider putting this file somewhere outside that directory.

Comment: I know this but it's a developer docker and hence I have volumes mapped. Please see updated `docker-compose.yml` snippet above

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this worked for me by amending `entrypoint.sh` with:

```sh
...
netlify dev | tee dev.log &
wait
```